# Javascript get raw date from date object

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, timezone

I'm implementing a Date Picker, using `react-datepicker`.  It gives a Date object back with the onChange event.  I'm trying to grab the date from that, to pass to an API.  The problem, though, is it is applying timezones, which potentially changes the dates.  I purely want the raw text from the date.  How do I go about doing that?  Here is a test case for what I am looking for

```
[
    new Date("2021-07-09"),
    new Date("2021/7/9"),
    new Date("2021.7.9"),
    new Date("07/09/2021"),
    new Date("07-09-2021"),
    new Date("07.09.2021"),
    new Date("7.9.21"),
    new Date("7/9/21"),
    new Date("7-9-21"),
    new Date("2021-07-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
    new Date("Wed, 09 July 2021 00:00:00 GMT"),
    new Date("Wed July 09 2021 21:57:30 GMT-0400 (Pacific Standard Time)"),
    new Date("2021/07/09")
  ].map(date => {
    const transformedDate = 'foo'; // Solution here
    return transformedDate;
  }).every(d => d === '2021-07-09');
```

When I tried `moment(date).utc(true).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` I get
[image: Wrong Dates]

When I tried `moment(date).utc(false).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` I get
[image]

Either way I'm getting a date that I don't want D: - Have a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-villani-wvqdn?file=/src/App.js) set up if anyone wants to experiment.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Hi, can you try with this: 

`moment(date).local(true).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

Comment: @RudraPratapSinha That makes these two fail `2021-07-09T00:00:00.000Z` and `Wed, 09 July 2021 00:00:00 GMT`.  They output `2021-07-08`